Declaration of support for Israel at the German naturalization ceremony
The long process is over, I finally have an appointment for the ceremony of obtaining the certificate of German naturalization.
I will have to swear an oath, which to my understanding I will repeat after an official.
I will also have to declare in writing my support for Israel.
The exact wording is (emphasis added):

Zusätzlich müssen Sie sich schriftlich zum Existenzrecht Israels bekennen.

Translation from German (via Google Translate):

In addition, you must declare in writing that you support Israel’s right to exist.

Does this mean that I have to memorize the whole text and write it?
That makes no sense:
the oath is much shorter, and even that I don’t have to memorize, just repeat after.
Or does it mean that I simply sign a document containing that declaration?

Translation from German: "In addition, you must declare in writing that you support Israel’s right to exist"

The key thing here is that giving false statements during a naturalization procedure may cause it to be revoked if the fraud can be proven. The signature shows that the applicants did read what they have signed. Congratulations on your new citizenship, btw.

@o.m. Well, a § 35 (1) StAG revocation is definitely applicable if you are lying about hard facts, but this is an opinion, not a hard fact that can be assessed in retrospect.

Well, going out after the ceremony and starting waving "from the river to the sea" signs may probably not work out very well. This is not a high bar to meet, but there are more than enough people who want to naturalize in Germany, but don't want to meet even the lowest bar of acknowledging other people's right to exist.

@KaiBurghardt, consider the comments made by various politicians when the requirement was introduced. Courts would have the last word, not the government, of course.

@littleadv It's not about people though and, interestingly, not about people living in Germany (which could be a meaningful oath, given the history you're alluding to in another comment). It's about a state, conveniently located far enough to avoid thinking too hard about the people who live in that state, whether they are Jewish or not, citizens or not. Based on the circumstances of its (very recent) addition, that seems to be its actual purpose: Whitewashing that history through slogans that implicitly shift the blame and burden of repairing it onto some vague “others”.

@Relaxed I'm afraid I don't understand your dog-whistles. Are you suggesting that Germany must allow genocidal people to naturalize? Because, given it's history, you know... Otherwise I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to convey. If the candidate is not a genocidal antisemite they should have no problem agreeing that Israel has a right to exist.

@littleadv I think it's a false alternative, I have been clear about that, no dog whistles involved.

Clearly not clear enough, because I don't understand what your objection is.

@littleadv Objection to what? I am just saying this requirement isn't and has never been about weeding out genocidal antisemites. I also believe you can be uncomfortable with that phrase (“Israel's right to exist”) without being an antisemite or even while firmly believing that Jews have a right to live in peace and security in Israel but the main point is that I don't think the people who introduced this additional oath care very deeply about all this. The requirement itself is pure posturing and dog whistle (to reuse this term).

I also don't see anything in the question suggesting the OP has any problem with the substance of the oath, it seems they were just (mistakenly) afraid they had to memorize a text to write it by hand.

I don't have anything against the OP or their question, I'm just trying to understand what is it that's so triggering for you here. You're the one who's ranting nonstop about how bad this declaration is and how awful are the politicians who want to ensure the newly minted citizens don't want to repeat what they themselves have done in their shameful past.

@littleadv I am not ranting non-stop, I merely explained my vote while you posted multiple comments and even explicitly pinged me. I obliged and clarified my thinking but if anything, it seems you were triggered by the question and very eager to initiate some discussion about the politics of that oath.


Schriftlich just means in writing.
This can be typewritten or an electronic printout.
There must be some kind of individualization though.
This means you place your signature below the text (below in accordance to the secondary writing direction of the utilized script).
The word handschriftlich means handwritten.
One case of setting up a handwritten document is the final will and testament (should you not opt for a notarized last will and testament).
Otherwise handwritten documents are virtually non‑existent in German legal practice.


Thank you for pointing out this important distinction between schriftlich and handschriftlich. I just thought that I already did this two weeks ago when I had an appointment to bring originals of the documents. There was also a survey on democratic order, basic human rights and a few questions about Israel.


I will also have to declare in writing my support for Israel.

That is a very misleading translation. You can be opposed to Israels current policies, opposed to civilians being killed by their military, opposed to much of what they do. You need to declare that you acknowledge their "right to exist". On the scale of respect and support that is probably the lowest bar there can possibly be.
If you take that and apply it to humans, the difference between supporting a presidential candidate, and acknowledging their right to exist (and not be assassinated) is huuuuge. Just because I think nobody should be assassinated does not exactly make me a "supporter".
So you need to acknowlegde their right to exist. You can be staunchly against anything they do, as long as you consider genocide the wrong solution to that problem.

"Zusätzlich müssen Sie sich schriftlich zum Existenzrecht Israels bekennen"

This is not a college application with essays. Germany can neither handle nor judge thousands of different wordings on this. Very likely it is a form that you read and then sign or it is part of a form you sign anyway. But just "saying it" during the ceremony is not enough. There has to be something in writing, that has to have your signature.
This by the way is not uncommon, you will find many instances in German law where "in writing" is required.
